# GTK Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm new to GTK+ and I get a segmentation fault error when I try to compile my program. I've isolated the cause of the error down to the following lines of code.

```
      GtkTextBuffer *buffer; 
      char buffers[65535];
      struct ip  *ip;          
      .
      .
      .
      ip = (struct ip *)buffers;
      gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor (buffer,ip->ip_protocol, -1);
```

(ip_protocol is a variable in the struct ip)

I'm trying to insert,at the cursor of a textview,the value of the char,"ip_protocol",situated in "buffers" using a pointer.Unfortunately I have to use a pointer in this case.Can anyone help with rectifying my code?

Answer (score 1):

<s>You never initialize your `buffer` variable (or the contents of `buffers` for that matter), so its value is undefined when you pass it do `gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor`. You need to make it point to a `GtkTextBuffer` before you pass it to the function.</s> (According to your comment you initialize your variables in the part of the code you left out, so this paragraph doesn't apply to your real code).

Furthermore you said that your `ip_protocol` variable is a `char`, but the second argument to `gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor` should be a pointer. So it's unsurprising that this causes a segmentation fault.

Comment: How do you initialize buffer? Buffers (bad name-I know) is initialized in a previous line, but it isn't the problem.

Comment: @Symbiotic_Chemistry That depends on what you want it to point to. If you want to point it to the buffer of an existing text view, you can use `buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(my_existing_text_view);`. If you want to create a new buffer, you can use `gtk_text_buffer_new`.

Comment: I've initialized `buffer` the way you mentioned. If you notice I skipped the parts that were irrelevant. What I'm trying to do is display the contents of `ip_protocol`, which is the problem within that function. I assure you that my code works correctly in other instances, except when I try to display the value of the variable `ip_protocol` (or any variable) that `ip` points to. I'd like to find out how to write the code correctly?

Comment: @Symbiotic_Chemistry Obviously those parts weren't irrelevant. Anyway, what's the value of `ip->ip_protocol`? Is it 0-terminated? Come to think of it: What's the type of `ip->ip_protocol`? In your question you called it a `char`. Was that a typo for `char*`? If not, the argument to `gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor` should be a 0-terminated string, not a `char`.

Comment: `ip` is pointing to an unsigned char (`ip_protocol)`. Any idea how I may be able to display `ip_protocol`?

Comment: @Symbiotic_Chemistry Do you want to display it as a char or as a number? If you want it as a char, you can just take its address and pass it to `gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor` with a length argument of 1 (so it just reads that one char and doesn't go looking for a 0-terminator). I don't think that the value of `ip_protocol` is likely to be a printable char though, so that's probably not what you want. If you want to display it as a number, you'll have to convert it to a string first and then display that.

Comment: I think I may have found the problem, In this line of code:`printf("Protocol ::: %d\n",ip->ip_protocol);` if you remove the parts `"Protocol ::: %d\n",` you get the same error when compiled, so I assume that the problem lies with omitting the `%d\n` part. My question is then, how do you incorporate `%d\n` into `gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor (buffer,ip->ip_protocol, -1);`?

Comment: @Symbiotic_Chemistry If you remove the "%d" part, you're passing the wrong number of arguments to `printf`. That's why you get a segfault there. Your call to insert_at_cursor segfaults because you pass a char where the function expects a pointer (which your compiler should have been warning you about by the way).